# Error while building aws_iot (thing shadow) example in release/v4.2 SDK

Tags: git, github, sdk, aws-iot, esp-idf

Hey everybody,
              In the release/v3.3 there exists an aws_iot example which does not exist in release/v4.2 of esp-idf.
              So I copied the aws_iot (thing shadow) example and made desired changes according to my requirement in the thing_shadow.c file and the aws_iot folder in components from v3.3 onto v4.2. But while building the example in the current SDK(v4.2) I am getting the following error.

ERROR:

WARNING: Missing submodule components/aws_iot/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C...
Attempting 'git submodule update --init components/aws_iot/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C' in esp-idf root directory...
error: pathspec 'components/aws_iot/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C' did not match any file(s) known to git.
/home/harshitha/esp32/esp-idf/make/project.mk:672: recipe for target '/home/harshitha/esp32/esp-idf/components/aws_iot/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/.git' failed
make: *** [/home/harshitha/esp32/esp-idf/components/aws_iot/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/.git] Error 1
How would I be able to solve this? Can someone please suggest the desired changes to be done in the current SDK version4.2  in order to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: Add "esp-aws-iot" as a component in your SDK

1. go to where you have the IDF SDK installed e.g `C:\ESP-IDF\esp-idf\components`
2. open a command prompt in that directory and get the idf package using this command
   `git clone --recursive https://github.com/espressif/esp-aws-iot`

EDIT: looks like maybe your path where you installed the component is wrong from your post its currently:
"/home/harshitha/esp32/esp-idf/components/**aws_iot**/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C"
Should be:
"/home/harshitha/esp32/esp-idf/components/**esp-aws-iot**/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C"

Ref: https://github.com/espressif/esp-aws-iot

Comment: Strongly suggest to add the component into your application instead of the IDF itself. You add a "components" folder inside your app directory. More information in the [ESP IDF programming guide](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html?highlight=external%20components#example-project).